# cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to upload my project on AWS and while deploying it via ElasticBeanStalk I get the follwing error:

> cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed

The project was already deployed on AWS and is working without any problem, there are no changes in `.ebextensions` files as well

db-migrate.config:

```
container_commands:
    01_migrate:
        command: "source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate"
        leader_only: true
```

Error stack:

```
2022-12-19 06:16:50,685 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2022-12-19 06:16:50,688 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2022-12-19 06:16:50,691 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_Trakkia_al2
2022-12-19 06:16:53,613 [ERROR] Command 01_migrate (source /var/app/venv/*/bin/activate && python3 manage.py migrate) failed
2022-12-19 06:16:53,614 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_Trakkia_al2: Command 01_migrate failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed
2022-12-19 06:16:53,617 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2022-12-19 06:16:53,617 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_migrate failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 137, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 564, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 576, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 276, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_migrate failed
```

I am unable to pinpoint the error origin from this

Comment: as @Mykola Rud suggested, taking a look to the init-cmd logs can give you a hint. This can happen for different reasons, a common one is if someone pipped a new package and they forgot to update the requirements (for example).

Answer (score 4):

take a look into /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log
In my case I found there is not enough free memory. Thus updating instance type with more memory helped (EBS-Config-Capacity-Instance types)